# Simplest expression for this angle?

Tags: trigonometry

We have a unit circle, a point $R = (\sin\theta,\cos\theta)$ on the circumference, and a point $P=(a,b)$ contained in the circle ($a^2+b^2<1$).

We know $a,b$ and $\theta$, and we want to find the angle $\phi$ between the line segment $\overline{PR}$ and the $y$-axis. I've summarized this in the image below:

[image: angle problem]

I suppose I could use cosine law but it seems to get real messy real fast. I'm pretty terrible at trigonometry so I wanted to ask here if there are any really nice/elementary solutions I'm just not seeing.

Answer (score 2):

$$\tan\phi=\left|\frac{\sin\theta-a}{\cos\theta-b}\right|$$
(Draw the axis-aligned right triangle with $PR$ as hypotenuse.)

Comment: Thanks. Is atan2 the best/only way to uniquely recover phi?